# I'm trying to figure out number of measures

Tags: tempo, beats

Im trying to figure the number of measures using the bpm and the length of the song. So I was wondering if you have any ways I could figure it out for me.

Answer (score 3):

Impossible in general. There's not enough information. For example, a song at 120bpm lasting 2 minutes would have 1bps but 30 measures in 4/4 and 40 measures in 3/4. Of course, should you have a good guess at the time signature, any of the two (length, time signature, bpm) can be computed from the other three.

Answer (score 2):

Multiply minutes by bpm, giving you total number of beats.   Pop and rock music is typically in 4/4 time, 4 beats per measure.  So divide by 4 to get number of measures.
If the music is more complex, you will have to be more clever.